# Collaboration Objective C and monotouch

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios

Could someone who programs in objective C collaborate with someone who programs in .net using monotouch on the same application?

It looks like you write your code in .net with monotouch and it stays that way.

Comment: Are you asking about collaborating, or about writing a single application in Objective-C _and_ .NET+MonoTouch?

Answer (score 3):

They can collaborate.   The Objective-C guy would have to produce a library that you could consume from C#.

Then you would use the btouch tool to generate a C# binding that can access the Objective-C code.

This means that the main program is driven from C#.

Here is a guide on binding Objective-C APIs to expose them to C#:

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types